# Search result from mongodb using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, web-services

i have collection in my mongodb named checkin for save record airport check in passengers i wanna show search result all nearby passengers who use our app form my lat-long but i search people only one hour before from user flight deparcher time

here is my efforts...

```
funcs.findcompanyon = function(request, reply) {
console.log(request.user._id);

var d = new Date();        
var da = d.getDate();      
var mon = d.getMonth() + 1;
var yr = d.getFullYear();
var t=d.getTime();

var thisDay = yr + "-" + mon + "-" + da;

console.log(thisDay);

var mintime = t - 7200000 ;
var maxtime = t + 7200000 ;
console.log(t);
console.log("MIN TIME:-"+mintime);
console.log("MAX TIME:-"+maxtime);

User.findById(request.user._id, function(err, user) {

    if (err) {
        reply(err).code(500);

    } else {

        Checkin.find({
            $and : [ 
            {
                checkindate : thisDay
            },
            {
                checkintime : {
                    $gte : mintime,
                    $lte : user.checkintime
                }
            }
            ]

        }).exec(function(err, route) {

            if (err) {
                reply(err).code(500);
            } else {
                return reply(route);
            }

        });

    }
});
```

};

my mongodb collection is here

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5767c0cd77edd4e01751a7db"),
"createdAt" : ISODate("2016-06-20T10:09:17.247Z"),
"updatedAt" : ISODate("2016-06-20T10:09:17.247Z"),
"userid" : "576793e60952af9411004a77",
"airportid" : "576273b183aa1edc11af367d",
"checkindate" : "2016-6-20",
"checkintime" : 1466417357243.0000000000000000,
"time" : 1466417123359.0000000000000000,
"__v" : 0
```

}

here time is flight deparcher time

Comment: R u getting any error?

Comment: after find method i have an array named user second parameter of my find method